# typescript にて typeで指定した型に代入にしようとすると配列を受け付けない

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

vsocdeで vue3 と typescriptでコードを書いています。
次のようなコードで typeで型指定後に obj から itemObj に値を移そうとするとエラーになります。

```
type Obj = {
  Timeline: {
    Items: ItemsObj[];
  };
};
type ItemsObj = {
  [key: string]: { 
    CharacterName: string;
  };
};

//略

const obj= ref<Obj>();
const itemsObj= ref<ItemsObj>();


//略

itemsObj.value = obj.value?.Timeline?.Items;
```

vscodeが `itemsObj.value` の部分で下記のようなエラーを出力します。
`型 'itemsObj[] | undefined' を型 'itemsObj | undefined' に割り当てることはできません。`

type obj の中で　itemsObj[] となっていますので、配列指定されています
type itemObj の中では　`[key:string]:{`　と配列を受け入れられる状態だと思います。

type itemObj の設定方法が間違っているような気はするのですが、
どのように書くことが正しいのかがわからずにいます。

修正すべきところを教えていただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記の修正で問題がなくなりました

```
type Obj = {
  Timeline: {
    Items: ItemsObj[];
  };
};
type ItemObj = {
  CharacterName: string; // 1)[key:string] を削除
};

//略

const obj= ref<Obj>();
const itemsObj= ref<ItemObj[]>([]); // 2)<>内を配列化 & 初期値空配列指定


//略

itemsObj.value = obj.value.Timeline.Items; // 3)? 削除
```

1. 配列のためのkeyとして設定していましたが、元データが連想配列ではなかったので削除
2. ジェネリックの中を配列として指定。これをしないと 1:1 の関係になりますね。更に初期化をしておかないと、typescriptが「undefinedの可能性あり」と判断します
3. 同様に変数の後ろに ? がある。ということは「undefinedの可能性あり」 と判断される

上記の修正によって、型を一致（あるいは認識）させることができるようになりエラーがなくなりました。

一つ一つをとってみると「そりゃそうだ」なのですが、同時に間違いがあるとお手上げになります。
これでまた一つの経験を得たので、同じミスはしないと思います（ちゃんと覚えておこう）